# Upload Upgrade Package Screen in Upgrade Wizard is Blank

Tags: php, sugarcrm

I am in between of upgrading our Sugar instance from its current version 6.3.1 to 6.4.6 via the Upgrade wizard, I could successfully go through the first step of System Check but then when I proceed forward to upload the upgrade package the screen blanks out. I made sure that the memory_limit and max_execution_time were appropriate in php.ini but that didn't help either. The upgrade wizard log doesn't help either, it simply says:

```
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:33:24 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - setting session variables...
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:33:24 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:33:24 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Upgrade started. At start.php
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:33:24 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - at unlinkTempFiles()
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:33:24 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - finished!
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:33:24 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - resetting $_SESSION
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:38:22 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - setting session variables...
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:38:22 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - [At systemCheck.php]
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:38:22 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Starting file permission check...
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:39:06 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Finished file permission check.
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:39:06 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Starting database permissions check...
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:39:06 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Checking CREATE TABLE permissions...
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:39:06 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Checking INSERT INTO permissions...
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:39:06 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Checking UPDATE TABLE permissions...
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:39:06 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Checking SELECT permissions...
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:39:06 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Checking validity of SELECT results
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:39:06 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Checking DELETE FROM permissions...
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:39:06 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Checking ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN permissions...
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:39:06 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Checking ALTER TABLE CHANGE COLUMN permissions...
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:39:06 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Checking ALTER TABLE DROP COLUMN permissions...
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:39:06 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Checking DROP TABLE permissions...
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:39:06 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - No permissions errors found!
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:39:06 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - Finished database permissions check.
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:44:18 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - setting session variables...
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:44:18 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - At upload.php
Wed, 29 Jan 2014 10:44:18 -0500 [UpgradeWizard] - finding new files for upgrade
```

As per this [blog](http://www.topwebhosts.org/bbs/board.php?bo_table=opensource_apps&wr_id=1) I modified the settings in php.ini to be:

```
max_execution_time = 14400 
max_input_time = 14400 
memory_limit = 768M 
post_max_size = 128M 
upload_max_filesize = 128M
```

but I still get blank screen. I tried restarting the server but that didnt help either. Any idea of what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Blank screens are usually signs of Fatal PHP errors, so you should first check your php and web server logs for more information.

If you find that you encounter issues with finding files and/or a suhosin configuration, you'll find tips and discussion here: http://www.profilingsolutions.com/archive/module-loader-screen-is-blank/